# Objective-c how to create lens flare effect in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to create the same effect that you can see on the picture attached.

[image: Effect I would like to create]

I would like to have that kind of effect over my barcode scanner, which scan barcode with phone camera.

Any idea how can I do this?

I already tried with shadows but that was not the effect I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 
`CILenticularHaloGenerator` core image filter simulates lens flare, although the appearance is different than what you show.

Your image looks more like a radial gradient in red drawn over your image. You could use the Core Image `CIRadialGradient` filter, or overlay a partly transparent gradient on top of your image using `CGGradient` and `CGContextDrawRadialGradient`.

Comment: I don't have image. I have live barcode scanner. I would like to simulate scanner with red line and lens flare effect. Please se my updated question. Sorry for poorly structured question.

Comment: So update your question to show how you are displaying the camera image. Include information about your UI setup.